# After server move postfix/dovecot problems

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have moved from one server provider to another porting all my domains and services. Everything went smoothly at first sight, but I realised now that i am having some problems with dovecot/postfix.

First problem: In the webinterface (Roundcube) I see all old mails with the correct timestamp, when getting them on a mailclient, I always see 5th May 2015 (one day after server has been moved) as date.

Second problem: I seem to not be able to send and receive mails via IMAP. I do not get an error (ill post the logs later in this post), it seems as if the mail has been sent.

Third problem: Logfile is spammed with this errors: `warning: 9C42A2408E2: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@dirty-harry -- message not accepted, try again later` (dirty-harry is my servers name!).

I have googled all of these problems, looked over my configurations again but cannot find anything that would solve my problem.

Here are the configurations:

**main.cf**

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/sslcert/mailserver.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/sslcert/mailserver.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = dirty-harry
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = static.136.90.47.78.clients.your-server.de, dirty-harry, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

disable_vrfy_command = yes

smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth_dovecot
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $smtpd_sender_login_maps

smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_sender_login_maps.cf

smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch
        reject_unknown_sender_domain

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated
        permit_mynetworks
        reject_unauth_destination


virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail/
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 112400000
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 104
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

**master.cf**

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache

maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix    -    n    n    -    2    pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
```

**dovecot.conf**

```
protocols = imap imaps pop3 pop3s

log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "

ssl_cert_file = /etc/postfix/sslcert/mailserver.crt
ssl_key_file = /etc/postfix/sslcert/mailserver.key

protocol pop3 {
  pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
}

protocol lda {
  postmaster_address = aender.mich@example.org
  auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
}

auth default {
  mechanisms = plain login

  passdb sql {
    args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf
  }

  userdb sql {
    # Path for SQL configuration file, see /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf for example
    args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf
  }

  user = root

  socket listen {
    master {
      path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
      mode = 0600
      user = vmail
    }
    client {
      path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth_dovecot
      mode = 0660
      user = postfix
      group = postfix
    }
  }
}
```

**mail.log** (Stripped down, these messaged repeat every second)

```
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/pickup[20017]: warning: B46BD2416D6: message has been queued for 6 days
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/pickup[20017]: B46BD2416D6: uid=0 from=<root>
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/cleanup[20080]: B46BD2416D6: message-id=<20150518042448.B46BD2416D6@dirty-harry>
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/cleanup[20080]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf lookup error for "root@static.136.90.47.78.clients.your-server.de"
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/cleanup[20080]: warning: B46BD2416D6: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@static.136.90.47.78.clients.your-server.de -- message not accepted, try again later
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/pickup[20017]: warning: B4B262416D6: message has been queued for 2 days
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/pickup[20017]: B4B262416D6: uid=0 from=<root>
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/cleanup[20080]: B4B262416D6: message-id=<20150518042448.B4B262416D6@dirty-harry>
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/cleanup[20080]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf lookup error for "root@static.136.90.47.78.clients.your-server.de"
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/cleanup[20080]: warning: B4B262416D6: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@static.136.90.47.78.clients.your-server.de -- message not accepted, try again later
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/pickup[20017]: warning: B4F932416D6: message has been queued for 8 days
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/pickup[20017]: B4F932416D6: uid=0 from=<root>
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/cleanup[20080]: B4F932416D6: message-id=<20150518042448.B4F932416D6@dirty-harry>
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/cleanup[20080]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf lookup error for "root@static.136.90.47.78.clients.your-server.de"
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/cleanup[20080]: warning: B4F932416D6: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@static.136.90.47.78.clients.your-server.de -- message not accepted, try again later
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/pickup[20017]: warning: B53FA2416D6: message has been queued for 3 days
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/pickup[20017]: B53FA2416D6: uid=0 from=<root>
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/cleanup[20080]: B53FA2416D6: message-id=<20150518042448.B53FA2416D6@dirty-harry>
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/cleanup[20080]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf lookup error for "root@static.136.90.47.78.clients.your-server.de"
May 18 06:24:48 dirty-harry postfix/cleanup[20080]: warning: B53FA2416D6: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@static.136.90.47.78.clients.your-server.de -- message not accepted, try again later
```

mail.err and mail.warn are empty.

I would be very greatful if someone could have a look at it! Thank you!

Comment: What was the exact nature of the porting process?

Comment: Can you post /etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf file ? Did you migrate the mysql database ?

Comment: Seems like you are not able to log into mysql database or the connections is not defined correctly.

Comment: I am very sorry to answer that late. One issue I have resolved, eltrai was right, there was a problem with the DB connection. I had a typo in the db name. I am now able to send mails, but I cant receive and dont get any error or any logentry, nor a error on the senders site. @Eltrai: I did migrate it, yes.

Comment: Okay, received **some** mails, but now I cant receive again....everything else works... No error in the filesy

Comment: I might have found the issue, i got the wrong DNS mx0 entry. Ill have to wait for DNS update on the remote servers now. Ill report back!

Comment: If the case was solved, feel free to put the answer in the box below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution now with the guys here at Server Fault.

There were two problems going on:

**Why wasnt I able to receive Mails?**

I migrated the server and updated the DNS A records, but forgot to update the mx records, so the old server was still receiving the mails, where postfix and dovecot were still running. Updating the mx record solved the issue.

**Why wasnt I able to send mails and got the log spammed?**

I had a typo in the postfix database name. Fixing that resolved that issue.